# Infinispan Server say "No security context found" when using REST endpoint

Tags: rest, infinispan

I'm trying Inifinispan server 7.1.1 and I get stuck with the REST endpoint service.

I kept the provided configuration then I used the `user-add.bat` script to add a user.

I launched one cluster node with `bin\clustered.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Djboss.node.name=nodeA`

but now if I try to use the rest API with wget :

`wget --http-user=user --http-password=mypass localhost:8180/rest/default/key`

I get :

```
00:18:55,414 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /rest/default/key: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS017329: No security context found
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:128) [wildfly-undertow-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:82) [wildfly-undertow-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.BasicAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(BasicAuthenticationMechanism.java:110) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:281) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:298) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:268) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:131) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:106) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:99) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:54) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:27) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS017329: No security context found
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:115) [wildfly-undertow-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 29 more
```

If I don't provide authentication information I get a "401 Unauthorized".

I took a look at configuration examples but I didn't see usefull help.
Any idea ?

Comment: Do you really need auth at REST level? You could disable it by removing `auth-method` and `security-domain` attributes from `rest-connector` in the `org.infinispan.server.endpoint` module configuration in the config used (I think it's `clustered.xml`)

Comment: Yes I need it. If I disable security on the REST endpoint I will have to delegate authentication to an other component (Apache). I would prefer to keep the structure as simple as possible.